# Can a BLE app look for the devices all the time, even if it is in background?

Tags: ios, btle

- If Yes, please explain, how we can implement this!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions like this are a bit out of scope, if you're looking for help, its best to show what you've tried and what research you've done.

Answer (score 0):

CoreBluetooth's programming guide explain this quite a bit.
Start reading [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1).